# Creating Multiple tables in Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Creating Multiple table in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8002394/creating-multiple-table-in-oracle)

I am using Oracle Express 10g and I'm enter the following text to create 2 tables in the sql command line, but it is not working.

```sql
CREATE TABLE student (
    matric_no     VARCHAR2(8),
    first_name    VARCHAR2(20),
    last_name     VARCHAR2(20),
    date_of_birth DATE
);

CREATE TABLE student1 (
    matric_no     VARCHAR2(8),
    first_name    VARCHAR2(20),
    last_name     VARCHAR2(20),
    date_of_birth DATE
);
```

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong.

The error messgae I get is:

```
ORA-00911: invalid character
```

Thanks

Comment: Can't repro, cut/paste-int that in sqlplus works just fine.

Comment: Please don't ask the same question twice.

Comment: How are you running it, what SQL command line are you using? SQL*Plus?, APEX Query Window?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you didn't type this out in WORD? 
Sometimes there are problems with "invisible" characters. For example if you hit TAB in WORD, it will store it as a special character which will thereby cause an error when you try running it in SQLPlus.

Comment: I did it in notepad but if I run either table seperatly it works fine

Answer (score 0):

try to create the two tables separate. First one and then the other, and without semicolon:

```
CREATE TABLE student (
    matric_no     VARCHAR2(8),
    first_name    VARCHAR2(20),
    last_name     VARCHAR2(20),
    date_of_birth DATE
)
```

Answer (score 0):

remove `";"` when you are editing your query in notepad and then give a try